# How does ruamel.yaml determine the encoding of escaped byte sequences in a string?

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am having trouble figuring out where to modify or configure [ruamel.yaml](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)'s loader to get it to parse some old YAML with the correct encoding. The essence of the problem is that an escaped byte sequence in the document seems to be interpreted as latin1, and I have no earthly clue where it is doing that, after some source diving [here](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/default/). Here is a code sample that demonstrates the behavior (this in particular was run in Python 3.6):

```py
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML()
yaml.load('a:\n  b: "\\xE2\\x80\\x99"\n')  # Note that this is a str (that is, unicode) with escapes for the byte escapes in the YAML document
# ordereddict([('a', ordereddict([('b', 'â\x80\x99')]))])
```

Here are the same bytes decoded manually, just to show what it *should* parse to:

```py
>>> b"\xE2\x80\x99".decode('utf8')
'’'
```

Note that I don't really have any control over the source document, so modifying it to produce the correct output with ruamel.yaml is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ruamel.yaml` doesn't interpret individual strings, it interprets the
stream it gets hanled, i.e. the argument to `.load()`. If that
argument is a byte-stream or a file like object then its encoding is
determined based on the BOM, defaulting to UTF-8. But again: that is
at the stream level, not at individual scalar content after
interpreting escapes.  Since you hand `.load()` Unicode (as this is
Python 3) that "stream" needs no further decoding.  (Although
irrelevant for this question: it is done in the `reader.py:Reader` methods `stream` and
`determine_encoding`)

The hex escapes (of the form `\xAB`), will just put a specific hex
value in the type the loader uses to construct the scalar, that is
value for key 'b', and that is a normal Python 3 `str` i.e. Unicode in
one of its internal representations.  That you get the `â` in your
output is because of how your Python is configured to decode it `str`
tyes.

So you won't "find" the place where `ruamel.yaml` decodes that
byte-sequence, because that is already assumed to be Unicode.

So the thing to do is that **you** double decode your double quoted
scalars (you only have to address those as plain, single quoted,
literal/folded scalars cannot have the hex escapes). There are various
points at which you can try to do that, but I think
`constructor.py:RoundTripConsturtor.construct_scalar` and
`scalarstring.py:DoubleQuotedScalarString` are the best candidates. The former of those might take some digging to find, but the latter is actually the type you'll get if you inspect
that string after loading when you add the option to preserve quotes:

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load('a:\n  b: "\\xE2\\x80\\x99"\n')
print(type(data['a']['b']))
```

which prints:

```
<class 'ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString'>
```

knowing that you can inspect that rather simple wrapper class:

```
class DoubleQuotedScalarString(ScalarString):
    __slots__ = ()

    style = '"'

    def __new__(cls, value, anchor=None):
        # type: (Text, Any) -> Any
        return ScalarString.__new__(cls, value, anchor=anchor)
```

"update" the only method there (`__new__`) to do your double
encoding (you might have to put in additional checks to not double encode all
double quoted scalars0:

```
import sys
import codecs
import ruamel.yaml

def my_new(cls, value, anchor=None):
    # type information only needed if using mypy
    # value is of type 'str', decode to bytes "without conversion", then encode
    value = value.encode('latin_1').decode('utf-8') 
    return ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.ScalarString.__new__(cls, value, anchor=anchor)

ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString.__new__ = my_new

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load('a:\n  b: "\\xE2\\x80\\x99"\n')
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
ordereddict([('a', ordereddict([('b', '’')]))])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have made it clear that I didn't think ruamel.yaml was decoding the stream (it obviously wasn't), but that I was looking for where in the stages after stream handling this was happening. I saw the DoubleQuotedScalarString types, but I wasn't able to piece together what was happening at the interpreter level to cause the encoding to be incorrect, so I appreciate you drilling it down to the \_\_new\_\_ function. A question remains, though: Why was `value`, at the point of this constructor, decoded as 'latin1'?

Comment: So far, I've drilled back to this point in the scanner: https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/bace8dc0e8f5d950b4e9a62457a7d892626f8e81/scanner.py#lines-1431, I will go further down this path and see if I can resolve from there.

Comment: SO. What I've done is get to [here](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/bace8dc0e8f5d950b4e9a62457a7d892626f8e81/scanner.py#lines-1437:1450), which shows Ruamel as interpreting each x as a unicode character. That led me to [here](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2776092), which notes that \x denotes an 8-bite Unicode sequence, meaning Ruamel's behavior is correct, and whatever inserted this YAML did it incorrectly. I'm accepting this answer, it does the job and led me on the path of discovery that got me to finally figure out what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: I think I did not read your comment all the way through. Sorry for that.